# Routing with Zend Framework 2 Restful Webservice

Tags: rest, routes, zend-framework2

I want to implement a RESTful webservice by using Zend Framework 2, more precisely 2.1.5. I got a 404 if I visit http://ehcserver.localhost/rest, the corresponding message is 'rest(resolves to invalid controller class or alias: rest)'. What went wrong?

You can see my source code in my github-repository:
https://github.com/Jochen1980/EhcServer/blob/master/module/Application/config/module.config.php

The route is defined like this:

```
return array(
    'router' => array(
        'routes' => array(
            'rest' => array(
                'type' => 'ZendMvcRouterHttpSegment',
                'options' => array(
                'route' => '/:controller[.:formatter][/:id]',
                'constraints' => array(
                    'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    'formatter' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    'id' => '[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*'
                ),
            ),
         ),
         'home' => array(
         ...
```

Comment: Do you actually have a `RestController` class in your `YourModule/Controller` folder. If so, have you mapped it in the `invokables` section of the `controllers` array in `module.config.php` ? ie., `'YourModule\Controller\Rest' => 'YourModule\Controller\RestController',`

Comment: Thanks Crisp, as you can see in my repository, I think I have done both. Any further advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your route doesn't define a namespace to which the controller belongs, you need to add a `__NAMESPACE__` to route `defaults`

```
        'rest' => array(
            'type' => 'ZendMvcRouterHttpSegment',
            'options' => array(
                'route' => '/:controller[.:formatter][/:id]',
                'defaults' => array(
                    // tell the router which namespace :controller belongs to
                    '__NAMESPACE__' => 'Application\Controller',
                ),
                'constraints' => array(
                    'controller' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    'formatter' => '[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_-]*',
                    'id' => '[a-zA-Z0-9_-]*'
                ),
            ),
        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure the type is valid?

```
type' => 'ZendMvcRouterHttpSegment',
```

to this

```
type' => 'Segment',
```